# AES instruction disable (false)

Tags: 16.04

I trying to enable AES instruction on my AMD A6-3410MX APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4 , Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Currently the status is:

```
  AES instruction                         = false
```

BIOS is not supporting option to enable or disable AES, Do someone have a solution for it?

Thank you

Comment: [The A6-3410MX is unlikely to have AES instructions](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i5-2520M-vs-AMD-A6-3410MX).

Comment: The AES support instructions are non-privileged ordinary instructions. There is no way for the BIOS (or any firmware) to enable or disable them. The CPU mentioned in the question simply does not support hardware AES acceleration.